# Methods to determine local extreme value of a special multivariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials, maxima-minima

Consider a special multivariate polynomial

\begin{equation*}
x^4+y^8+z^2+\alpha xy^2z+\beta x^2y^4+\gamma xy^6.
\end{equation*}
Each term has the form $x^iy^jz^k$ satisfying $\frac{i}{4}+\frac{j}{8}+\frac{k}{2}=1$, and $(i,j,k)$ all lying on the triangle with vertices $(4,0,0),(0,8,0),(0,0,2)$.

The question is what methods can be used to determine a local extreme value at $(0,0,0)$?

My approach is to let $u=x^2,v=y^4,w=z$ which make it into a homogeneous, quadratic form
\begin{equation*}
u^2+v^2+w^2+\alpha u^{1/2}v^{1/2}w+\beta uv+\gamma u^{1/2}v^{3/2},
\end{equation*}
but the exponents are not all integers, meaning it is not defined for negative numbers.

How to fix it, or should I use a different method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Compute the three partial derivatives of the original function
$$F(x,y,z)=x^4+y^8+z^2+\alpha xy^2z+\beta x^2y^4+\gamma xy^6$$
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{dx}=4 x^3+2 \beta  x y^4+\gamma  y^6+\alpha  y^2 z\tag1$$
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{dy}=4 \beta  x^2 y^3+6 \gamma  x y^5+2 \alpha  x y z+8 y^7\tag2$$
$$\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{dz}=\alpha  x y^2+2 z\tag3$$

Use $(3)$ to get $$z=-\frac{1}{2} \alpha  x y^2$$ Plug it in $(1)$

$$4 x^3-\frac{y^4 \left(\alpha ^2-4 \beta
   \right)}{2} x +\gamma   y^6=0$$ which is a cubic equation in $x$.

Once solved, replace $x$ in $(2)$ and solve for $y$
$$y^3\left( 8 y^4+6 \gamma  x y^2-x^2 \left(\alpha ^2-4 \beta
   \right)\right)=0$$ where $x$ is a function of $y$.

Have fun for the last part.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to determine whether it has a local extreme at $(0,0,0)$, not trying to find all the max/mins.